# How to use function variables in the main?

Tags: c++, function, vector

Hey i have a function that contains the STL container vector.

```
void displayInventory()
{
    vector<string> inventory;
    cout<< "You have " << inventory.size() << " items.\n";
    cout<< "\nYouritems:\n";
    for (int i= 0; i< inventory.size(); ++i)
    cout<< inventory[i] << endl;
}
```

And i wanna use the actual vector in another method play game.

```
int playGame()
{
    inventory.push_back("sword"); //This is an error. Expression must have class.
}
```

Can anyone help me do this without having to globalize the vector declaration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive it as a function parameter:

```
int playGame(vector<string>& inventory)
{
    inventory.push_back("sword");
}
```

Comment: I did that which is fine but now im gettin thse two errors.  Error 7 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl playGame(void)" (?playGame@@YAHXZ) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\DKIT - Year 2 - Repeat\DKIT - Year 2 - Semester 1 - Repeat\Games Programming\MaroonedCA1\MaroonedCA1\MaroonedCA1.obj MaroonedCA1
Error 8 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\DKIT - Year 2 - Repeat\DKIT - Year 2 - Semester 1 - Repeat\Games Programming\MaroonedCA1\Debug\MaroonedCA1.exe 1 1 MaroonedCA1

Comment: @Prendo826: you also have to change the call to `playGame`, to pass the inventory as an argument. You haven't shown that call in your code, but I'm guessing it's not in `displayInventory`. As such, the basic problem is that you've defined `inventory` in the wrong place. Move it to somewhere that it can be passed into *both* `playGame` and `displayInventory`.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the vector by reference to the two functions and declare it in main?

```
int main()
{
  vector<string> inventory;
  playGame(inventory);
  displayInventory(inventory);
}

void displayInventory(vector<string> &inventory)
{
  inventory.push_back("string");
}

void playGame(vector<string> &inventory)
{
  inventory.push_back("A second string");
}
```